# How to conditionally replace NaN values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

[image: This is a sample of my dataset]

I want to replace nan values in column WL1 with values in a dictionary according to the Month column

This is the dictionary:
{'WL1': {1: 176.316,
2: 176.296,
3: 176.2825,
4: 176.398,
5: 176.52,
6: 176.576,
7: 176.558,
8: 176.519,
9: 176.479,
10: 176.382,
11: 176.36,
12: 176.353}}

For example, if df['Month'] == 1 and the value in WL1 is a NaN value, then we replace the nan with 176.326. If there is no nan values, we replace nothing.

Could anyone please show me how to code it out?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for clear question and examples! To get help faster, please, avoid using screenshot of a table to provide an example of dataset. The best way is either copy-pasteble text or code that generates dataset. Please, refer to this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fillna` can take a series to replace NaN values with. Non-NaN values are left untouched.

Replace the month numbers with the values from your `dictionary` with `map`, then pass the result to `fillna`:

```py
df["WL1"] = df.WL1.fillna(df.Month.map(dictionary["WL1"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dictionary to `pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame`, then `merge` it with the original dataset on `Month` column, then use `fillna`. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(WL1=[np.nan, np.nan, 177.26], Month=[1, 2, 3]))
replacememnts = {
    "WL1": {
        1: 176.316,
        2: 176.296,
        3: 176.2825,
    }
}
repl_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(repl=replacememnts["WL1"]))
df.merge(repl_df, left_on="Month", right_index=True).assign(
    WL1=lambda x: x["WL1"].fillna(x["repl"])
).drop(columns=["repl"])
```